# How to host my SPA? Make example.com/spa lead to CDN?

Tags: html, apache, dns, single-page-application, cdn

## Current state

I have an existing SPA application that runs against a backend server.

I have Apache being setup on my production server in the following way:

- DNS example.com points to my production server. There is Apache with proper SSL configuration for my domain
- example.com/frontend leads to SPA files (js/css/...) that are deployed in a folder of my server
- example.com/ leads to my backend which runs on the same server

## What I'd like to do

I'm trying to deploy my frontend assets to a CDN. There are many options here, but I'm not looking for advices on which one to choose.

## Problem

If I'm deploying my app to a CDN, files won't be hosted on my production server anymore. So I'll have my backend on example.com, and SPA on myapp.cdn.com

As far as I know it's not possible at the DNS level to make example.com/cdn points to the CDN files. At best I can create another domain cdn.example.com and make it point to myapp.cdn.com but unfortunatly it's not possible in my case...

There is an inconsistent behavior in Safari History API that other browsers don't have.

My index html page is served by my backend server (https://example.com/, and set as base url my frontend url (https://example.com/frontend). It currently works fine in all browsers because it's the same domain.

In Safari, if you set a base url of a different domain than the backend base url (using for example https://frontend.example.com/ as base url instead of https://example.com/frontend), then there are security exceptions that prevent my app to use HMTL5 History API normally.

## What I'm looking for

I already know some alternative options, like serving my index.html page directly in the frontend, or not using a base url. Not looking for such kind of solutions at the moment (even if I'm considering them for long terme changes)

What is the best way, on the same domain as my backend server (example.com), to make a path (like example.com/cdn) points to my CDN files?

I'm looking for a production-ready solution, where performance remains correct, and my CDN capabilities still kicks in (etags caching, HTTP2...)

I think my Apache server could eventually receive all requests on /cdn and issue permanent redirects to the CDN domain. Even if it involves an additional roundtrip for the first service, I would be ok with it as long as it's only the first time. Does it look like a production-ready option to you? Is there any decent alternative?

Answer (score 3):

Typically you'd want your frontend to be available at the root domain `example.com/`, no? The backend can be anywhere, it doesn't matter, since no user will see it.

What I would recommend:

- use a CDN that lets you use your own domain name
- use a CDN that is a mere caching proxy, not something you manually push static files to
- set up your DNS to point `example.com` to the CDN servers
- set up your backend at `backend.example.com`, not CDN'd
- set up the CDN to pull files from `backend.example.com`
- make backend requests to `example.com/api/...`

```
  +-----+
  | CDN | \
  +-----+  \
example.com \
             \
  +-----+     \  +--------+
  | CDN | ------ | origin |
  +-----+     /  +--------+
example.com  backend.example.com
            /
  +-----+  /
  | CDN | /
  +-----+
example.com
```

This way:

- `example.com/` is your one canonical world-visible URL
- the file layout mirrors the origin server exactly, no need to have two versions
- all requests are proxied through the CDN, including backend requests, which decreases load on the backend server and speeds up frontend responsiveness if you use caching correctly

Comment: That seems a sane approach. We already use S3/CloudFront for user-generated assets with a custom domain. However, my backend should absolutly receive requests on `/`. My SPA does not handle unauthenticated users. The backend actually redirects to the SPA, or to the homepage if the user is not authenticated. Also, I have to serve the SPA index.html page from the backend to be able to put some dynamic variables in the page (could probably work around that and serve a static index.html page but it probably won't be that easy due to legacy and some external tools we are using).

Comment: Well, this approach still lets you do all this.

Comment: Hmm I think I misunderstood. So you mean all my files should actually be hosted on my backend, and fetched/cached lazily on the CDN right? That seems a nice idea. Never used a CDN like that yet. Is it something common to go through a CDN before reaching an API? No problem with cookie-based auth etc?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. You simply need to be very conscious of your caching headers and selectively specify what can and cannot be cached. You typically tweak that in the web server configuration of your backend (not the application layer). You need to configure the CDN to forward certain headers and/or cookies to your backend, which will also influence how it caches or doesn't cache them. CloudFront can be configured quite well in this regard.

Comment: thanks for the pointers. I'll consider that in the future, but currently I can't invest much time in doing all the required changes to test this quite different architecture

Comment: Still, if the CDN has cached SPA assets, and I redeploy my backend/SPA assets, how can the CDN know when to invalidate its cached assets? This is something I would absolutely not want: my clients downloading a not up-to-date js file leading to the app not working at all.

Comment: @SebastienLorber Depends on the expected life time of assets. Either keep cache times at, e.g., ~1h and accept that assets may be out of date for 1h, or trigger an explicit invalidation request when you update.

Comment: According to what I've read, a manual invalidation request can take up to 10 minutes on cloudfront. Honnestly this is already too much for me. I really don't want that problem. I'm migrating frontend to a CDN not only for speed, but also to solve that specific invalidation problem (don't know why, seems my production Apache does not want to answer NotModified)

Comment: Yes, anecdotally 10m sounds about right. If that's not acceptable, how about traditional cache buster methods (appending versioning strings to assets)?

Comment: If I deploy 2 times my SPA application, most likely my bundle containing js libraries (separate from app code) will not change (unless I upgrade/add a library). I want to avoid a cache miss of clients on this file that can be quite big on every deployment. I want to be able to deploy 10 times a day, and the user should never have to download this file it it's always the same. I can surely use versions in the url but then I must manage different versions for app and lib code which seems quite depressing to me. I think I'm going to try `now serve` of `zeit.co`, it can be a good solution.